# Resize View in dp

Tags: java, android, listview, view

I'm stuck trying to resize the width of a View in a ListView programmatically, because I want it to be in DP, not pixels.

My ListView generate instances of a RelativeLayout with a View that fills all the screen (match_parent), and a TextView and a button inside.

The View is set to width = match_parent to fill the whole screen, as intended

[image]

What I want, is to have different View width in my adapter. Like 25%, 50%, or 75% of the total width of the base View.

```
mRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(**[VALUE I NEED HERE]**, mRelativeLayout.getLayoutParams().height));
```

The ImageView is set to width = match_parent

So this are the relevant parts of code in my ViewList adapter :

```
    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.test_layout);

    mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(arrayListName.myColor);

    if (arrayListName.myColor == R.color.custom ) {
        dayviewLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( 25% , dayviewLayout.getLayoutParams().height));
    }

    if (days.mMoodColor == R.color.custom2) {
        dayviewLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( 50% , dayviewLayout.getLayoutParams().height));
    }

    if (days.mMoodColor == R.color.custom3) {
        dayviewLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( 75% , dayviewLayout.getLayoutParams().height));
    }
```

The 25-50-75% are obviously wrong, as it takes only int values. I want it to fit any screen.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Take a look at [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

`dp` units are just `px` units multiplied by the current screen density, which is available via the `DisplayMetrics` class:

```
float density = [some context].getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int dp = (int) ([your px value] * density);
```